# Else condition in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript

I have a program like this

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile (firstName, prop) {
    // Only change code below this line

    for (var i = 0; i <= contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName===firstName) {
            if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                return contacts[i][prop];
            } else {
                return "No such property";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes");
```

The problem is that if I do not use `else` condition, the above code works with no problem. But when I add `else` condition, the first condition does not execute.

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile (firstName, prop) {
    // Only change code below this line

    for (var i = 0; i <= contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
            if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                return contacts[i][prop];
            } else {
                return "No such property";
            }
        } else if (contacts[i].firstName !== firstName) {
            return "No such contact";
        }
    }
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes");
```

When I execute this code with `else` condition, the first condition does not execute and jumps directly to the `else` condition. What step am I missing or doing wrong please?

Comment: What happen if multiple users with the same `firstName`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `else` part to the end of the function, because a single `return` like in the for loop, ends the function immediately.

```js
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {              // no i <= contacts.length
        if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
            if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                return contacts[i][prop];
            } else {
                return "No such property";
            }
        }
    }
    return "No such contact";
}

var contacts = [{ firstName: "Akira", lastName: "Laine", number: "0543236543", likes: ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"] }, { firstName: "Harry", lastName: "Potter", number: "0994372684", likes: ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"] }, { firstName: "Sherlock", lastName: "Holmes", number: "0487345643", likes: ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"] }, { firstName: "Kristian", lastName: "Vos", number: "unknown", likes: ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"] }];

console.log(lookUpProfile("Houdini", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "friends"));
```

A short way would be the use in ES6 of [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: the problem is not with "No such property", Problem is with the condition which tells there is no such content.
else if(contacts[i].firstName!==firstName)
        {
          return "No such contact";
        }

Comment: As an explanation, it should be noted that when you `return` something, it marks the end of the function and no further steps/loops will be processed.

Comment: These solution is not handling multiple Objects in `contacts` array with the same `firstName`.. Check my answer

Comment: @YosvelQuintero, i think, it's not ment for multiple occurence of the same first name.

Comment: firstNames was and will be never unique.. I think developers should make improvements if possible ;)

Comment: the answer selects the first occurence of firstname. please ask the op.

Answer (score 1):

`return` statement stops execution of the loop and exits the current function. return always exits its function immediately, without proceeding the further execution if it's inside a loop.

Alternatively, I suggest the **@Nina Scholz** answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following function should work ok:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) 
{
  for(var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)
  {
     if(contacts[i].firstName==firstName)
     {
       if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
       {
         return contacts[i][prop];
       }
       else 
       {
         return "No such property";
       }
     }
  }
  return "No such contact";
}
```

In the original function I see three problems:

1) Problem in the for -loop condition

The original for-loop was the following

```
for(var i=0; i<=contacts.length; i++)
```

In the loop the stop condition was i <= contacts.length. The 
contacts array is having zero -based indexing, thus the original
condition was: i is "less than equal" as contacts.length. The problem
is that the length of contacts is 4, but as the indexing is zero -based,
you will get an error when i incrments to 4 and thus goes over the array's
boundaries. Therefore the condition must be i is "less than" contacts.length.

Fix: `for(var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)`

2) Extra "=" in the if -clause:

```
if(contacts[i].firstName===firstName)
```

Fix:

```
if(contacts[i].firstName==firstName)
```

3) Else if -condition triggers always if firstName is not the 1st index

The else if -condition triggers always if the first contact is not the
one that we're looking for, i.e. if if(contacts[i].firstName==firstName) fails,
then else if will be true.

Fix:
Move the 'return "No such contact";' to the end of the function. As we return
value from the other branches already, it's more convenient to return
"No such contact" in the end if we didn't get a match.

Hopefully this helps a bit. I'm happy to help more if you have further questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is practically you enter your loop, check the first contact to see if is the contact you're looking for, and if isn't, before you have a chance to check the other contacts, you see the `return "No such contact";` line and exit function.

As in **@Nina Scholz**'s answer, you can carry the `return` to the end, because you know that if you reach that point, you have looked through all contacts and haven't returned from the function.

I don't have enough reputation to comment - and as this is an answer, I present achieving this with minimum edits on your code:

```
function lookUpProfile (firstName, prop) {
    // Only change code below this line

    for (var i = 0; i <= contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
            if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                return contacts[i][prop];
            } else {
                return "No such property";
            }
        } 
    }

    //At this point you know for sure that you haven't 
    //found the contact you're looking for.
    return "No such contact";
}
```

Comment: you need to eliminate the else part.

Comment: The first else? Why? To me it means I have found the correct person, but they don't have the property I'm looking for. For example, `lookUpProfile("Harry", "dislikes");`

Comment: but you return to early, because you could have later some find.

Comment: But if I found the contact with that name, and they don't have the property I'm looking for, why would I keep looking? Of course I'm assuming that contacts have unique names, otherwise it would make no sense to search for a specific person. (If there are two Harry's, whose likes am I going to return? Makes no sense.)

Comment: If the name & surname combination was unique instead, you could edit the function parameters and the if condition to reflect that - and you would still be able to use the else condition, because once you've found the right person, you've found the right person.